# В какой переменной находится расположение vim?

Tags: cmd, vim, переменные-среды

Ставил на комп vim, гладко поставился, запускается через командную строку, если ввести `vim`. Решил через тот же установщик поставить на ноутбук, но тут он так не запускается через командную строку. Очевидно что в переменные среды он не записался. На компьютере посмотрел расположение vim и переменные среды.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На сколько я понимаю переменные среды не поддерживают вложенность директорий. То есть если есть переменная `D:\123`, а программа находится в `D:\123\321\program.exe`, то винда не будет видеть эту программу.

**Так что вот вопросы:**

- Какая переменная у меня отвечает за расположение vim (так как у меня нет расположения `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` среди путей)?
- Если вручную добавить путь vim в переменную на ноутбуке, то все ли
  будет гладко работать, ведь это должен был сделать установщик?

Comment: В PATH добавлять ничего не надо, он будет работать и так. А в первом случае видимо есть запись в PATH в системных переменных.

Comment: @user7860670 так вот не работает почему то. `vim не является внутренней или внешней командой`

Comment: Следует всегда прописывать полные пути к файлам.